# PS error when enforcing Smartcard attribute

Tags: powershell

I am receiving error message when running the following script, any idea why?

```
PS C:\Users\npevltdisdddtda_1> $userList = Import-Csv C:\temp\Text.csv
foreach ($user in $userList) {
    
       # Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.SamAccountName)'" | {Set-ADUser -SmartCardLogonRequired:$true} 
        Get-ADUser -filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.SamAccountName)'" | {Set-ADUser -SmartcardLogonRequired:$true}
}
```

```
At line:5 char:77
+ ... ($user.SamAccountName)'" | {Set-ADUser -SmartcardLogonRequired:$true}
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

Comment: Remove the brackets from `Set-ADUser`.

Comment: Thanks @Santiago Squarzon, it worked like a charm